# Dockerfile copy files between in host before run in container

Tags: docker, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui which requires semantic.json located in root folder and set setting autoInstall: true when using Dockerfile.

In case I want to use custom theme, I need to rebuild semantic-ui which gulp requires semantic.json located in root-fooder/semantic/. That means, before building the image, the semantic.json should be located in semantic folder, copy to root folder then, after npn install and ng server, it should remove semantic.json in root folder to let gulp can run.

```
FROM node:8.11.3

WORKDIR /app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
COPY semantic.json /app

RUN npm install -g npm@latest \
    && npm install -g n \
    && npm install -g @angular/cli \
    && npm install -g gulp \
    && npm install gulp \
    && npm install

# add app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4200

# start app
CMD ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0
```

My question is how can I use Dockerfile to copy semantic.json file from semantic folder to root folder in host and build it, then remove it in root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding solution work-around, I update semantic.json to point base path to root folder and remaining paths will go to semantic as prefix as followings

```
    "base": "",
    "paths": {
        "source": {
            "config": "semantic/src/theme.config",
            "definitions": "semantic/src/definitions/",
            "site": "semantic/src/site/",
            "themes": "semantic/src/themes/"
        },
        "output": {
            "packaged": "semantic/dist/",
            "uncompressed": "semantic/dist/components/",
            "compressed": "semantic/dist/components/",
            "themes": "semantic/dist/themes/"
        },
        "clean": "semantic/dist/"
    },
    "permission": false,
    "autoInstall": true,
    "rtl": false,
    "version": "2.3.3"
```